# Display custom Devise Forgot your password form anywhere

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'd like to display a custom Devise 'Forgot your password' form anywhere, I figured it would be similar to https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app

So in `config/routes.rb` I added:

```
get "/forgot_password" => "desktop#new"
```

In `app/views/desktop/new.html.haml`:

```
      =form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => password_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :post }) do |f|
        .error-messages
          =devise_error_messages!
        =f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true, :required => true, :class => 'field'
        %br
        %br
        %button.signin-button Send Instructions
```

In `app/controllers/desktop_controller.rb`:

```
class DesktopController < ApplicationController
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end

  def new
  end
end
```

When I navigate to /forgot_password, I get a `undefined local variable or method 'resource'` error.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed

```
helper_method :resource, :resource_name, :devise_mapping
```

Right after the methods in desktop_controller.rb

Answer (score 0):

better to define that methods in your application helper

```
module ApplicationHelper

def resource_name
   :user
  end

  def resource
   @resource ||= User.new
  end

 def devise_mapping
 @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
 end
 end
```